# When can't spaces of correspondences distinguish type $II_{1}$ factors?

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

If $M$ is a type $II_{1}$ factor with trace $\tau$, let $Corr(M)$ denote the space of unitary equivalence classes of $M-M$ correspondences (binormal $M-M$ bimodules) equipped with Popa's analogue of Fell's topology. All details of the above can be found in [here](http://www.math.ucla.edu/~popa/popa-correspondences.pdf).

> What are some examples of
>   pairs of nonisomorphic type $II_{1}$ factors
>   $M,N$ such that their associated
>   spaces of correspondences $Corr(M),
> > Corr(N)$ are homeomorphic?